# LiOH base ionization reaction

Tags: acid-base

What is the base ionization reaction for LiOH? Usually, the reaction is like this: $$Base + \ce{H2O->H}[Base] + \ce{OH-} $$

But $\ce{LiOH2+}$ makes no sense. So what could the reaction be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you call *bases* is in fact a subset thereof. Besides that, there is a whole class of inorganic bases, also known as [alkali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkali). These are the hydroxides (sometimes called *basic salts*) of alkaline metals. Their ionization is somewhat different:
$$\ce{NaOH->Na+ + OH-}$$